# Using the gutter button to run tests always creates a new configuration

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When running tests from the gutter like so

[image: Run Test From Gutter]

A Run/Debug Configuration will get created. After setting all the properties, if I try to use that button again, another configuration will be created with `(1)` appended on the end. However, if I run the test from the top toolbar here:

[image: Run in top toolbar]

Then the test runs with the configuration specified. How can I get the gutter button to use the configuration after it is created and not create a new temporary configuration every time?

**Update**

Here is a simple test case and the configurations it generates

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class GutterReproduce {
    @Test
    public void SampleTest(){
        String env = System.getProperty("environment");

        Assert.assertEquals(env, "dev");
    }
}
```

And here are the configurations that it generates:

[image: Initial Configuration]

[image: Additional Configuration]

Comment: Did you try to Save the temp configuration?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, I saved the first temp configuration that was created, but then it just wanted to create another one

Comment: Please tell if the issue is reproduced for you with IDEA 2019.1.3? Please share the test sample and the screenshot of the configuration created. Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho I am using 2019.1.3. Added some samples

Comment: Thanks for providing the sample. Run test from gutter creates run configuration from the template (Run/Debug configurations | Template | Junit). In case such configuration is already created, it is used. In case created from template configuration in changed (in your case VM option is added), run test from gutter creates new configuration from template. You may change template configuration, adding "-ea -Denvironment=dev" VM options so that each time your run configuration from gutter the once created configuration is used.

Answer (score 0):

@Olga Klisho had the answer in the comments. By moving the configuration changes to the template, I was able to run and debug using the gutter button instead of having to choose a configuration and run it from the top toolbar.

> Thanks for providing the sample. Run test from gutter creates run configuration from the template (Run/Debug configurations | Template | Junit). In case such configuration is already created, it is used. In case created from template configuration in changed (in your case VM option is added), run test from gutter creates new configuration from template. You may change template configuration, adding "-ea -Denvironment=dev" VM options so that each time your run configuration from gutter the once created configuration is used